# The normal vector to a plane ax+by+cz+d=0?

Tags: mathematics, vector

I am calculating the normal vector to a plane ax+by+cz+d=0

According to the book:

The normal vector N is often normalized to unit length because in that case
the equation

```
d = N ⋅Q + D
```

gives the signed distance from the plane to an arbitrary point Q. If d = 0, then the
point Q lies in the plane. If d > 0, we say that the point Q lies on the positive side
of the plane since Q would be on the side in which the normal vector points.

How to get the N (Normal vector)? Thank you

Answer (score 13):

From [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NormalVector.html):

Given the plane

[image]

Then the normal vector is

[image]

The normal unit vector **n** is given by:

[image]

Therefore, for the plane `5x+2y+3z-1=0`,

The normal vector **N** is

> **N** = [5,2,3]

The magnitude **|N|** is

> **|N|** = sqrt(5^2 + 2^2 + 3^2)
>
> **|N|** = 6.1644

The normal unit vector **n** is therefore approximately:

> **n** = **N** / **|N|**
>
> **n** = [0.8111, 0.3244, 0.4866]

which you can check by measuring the length of **n**.

Code:

```
import math

def mag(V):
  return math.sqrt(sum([x*x for x in V]))
def n(V):
  v_m = mag(V)
  return [ vi/v_m for vi in V]
```

In an interactive python shell:

```
>>> N = [5,2,3]
>>> mag(N)
6.164414002968976
>>> n(N)
[0.8111071056538127, 0.3244428422615251, 0.48666426339228763]
>>> mag(n(N))
1.0
```