# What is a normalized Vector?

Tags: c#, game-design, movement

Can someone explain the following code? I need to learn what each part means so I can turn it into enemy movement in a space shoot-em-up

```
Vec2d playerPos;
Vec2d direction; // always normalized
float velocity;
```

I get the above is naming two 2d Vector objects, and creating a variable called velocity. I'm not sure what the normalized comment is about, though.

```
update()
{
   direction = normalize(playerPos - enemyPos);
   playerPos = playerPos + direction * velocity;
}
```

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/27787/14444) to a previous question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should read this tutorial on vectors for game developers at Wolfire: [Linear Algebra for Game Developers Part 1](http://blog.wolfire.com/2009/07/linear-algebra-for-game-developers-part-1/) / [Part 2](http://blog.wolfire.com/2009/07/linear-algebra-for-game-developers-part-2/)

A vector can be seen as pointing to a specific coordinate. It can also be seen as having a direction and a magnitude (or length).

A normalized vector is one that has a magnitude (or length) of exactly 1. Normalizing a vector produces a vector pointing in exactly the same direction, with a length of exactly 1.